# Apache not starting, nothing in log files despite being "debug" level

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, mod-ssl

Our cloud hosting company decided today to upgrade all CentOS implementations to 2.6.39.2. Unfortunately this had an adverse affect on our Apache server, preventing it from starting with mod_ssl enabled.

We're running Apache (ITK) 2.2.19 and have release 45.el5.centos.1 of the mod_ssl module installed. Both items have been reinstalled and reconfigured with the same result, when `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` is enabled, the Apache service fails to start with the only line appearing in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` being:

`[Sun Jul 10 19:39:03 2011] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 256 bytes of entropy`

I'm wondering if it might be something to do with the SSL certificates...and whether we might have to rebuild them from Thawte..?

Apache log level is set to debug;

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep LogLevel
LogLevel debug
```

Any tips on getting more detailed logs or any hints on where to go next?!

I'm totally baffled.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is `SELinux`. I don't know exactly why, but `OpenSSL 0.9.8` triggers a SELinux policy violation ("stack execute") on my Fedora machine, and it might prevent apache from starting. (I've turned SELinux into permissive mode, so I just watch the popup window without any possible consequences...)

Comment: We disabled `SELinux` when we set up the machine as it caused huge headaches with other things... any other ideas? (cheers for the reply!)

Answer (score 0):

Thorough rebuilding of Apache & all virtual host configs finally fixed the issue. Still not 100% sure as to what the actual problem was though..! Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Update from OP:

This curious error happened again and after some more careful debugging it looks like it was down to the default "localhost" certificate being used - not sure why but Apache decided it no longer liked it and would crash when starting. A rebuild of that with genkey sorted it out & everything working again as normal!